# Several threads: catching the moment when they all finish work

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have several threads, I need to catch the moment when they all finish work.
How to do it?

```
for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
   std::thread threads1(countFile, i);
   i++;
   std::thread threads2(countFile, i);
   threads1.detach();
   threads2.detach();
}

// wait until all the threads run out---

// to do next function ob object which uses by threads--
```

Comment: Call join on all of them. Did you read the docs to see what the methods do?

Answer (score 1):

Consider creating the `std::thread` objects outside the `for`-block and calling `join()` instead of `detach()`:

```
// empty (no threads associated to them yet)
std::array<std::thread, 2> threads1, threads2;

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
   threads1[i] = std::thread(countFile, i+1); // create thread
   i++;
   threads2[i] = std::thread(countFile, i+1); // create thread
}

// ...

// join on all of them
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
   threads1[i].join();
   threads2[i].join();
}

// at this point all those threads have finished
```

Not calling `detach()` implies that the call to `join()` has to be made **before** the destructor of the `std::thread` objects gets called (regardless of whether the thread has already finished or not).

For that reason I placed the `std::thread` objects out of the `for`-block. Otherwise, `join()` would have to be called inside the `for`-block.

Comment: but if I have 20 threads and I want them to be executed at one time?
I tried to use join, but it looked like, that every next thread crating in loop wait previously.
I just want to detect, when everything will be completed, and after that write result.

Comment: Did you use `join()` inside the loop?

Comment: Inside) and its not correct , i think I understood how it works

Comment: Placing `join()` outside, as in the code above, will block the main thread **after** it has launched all the threads, not between thread creation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use join and not detach threads from the main thread.

```
std::vector<std::thread> th1, th2;


for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
   th1.push_back(std::thread(countFile, i+1));
   i++;
   th2.push_back(std::thread(countFile, i+1));
}

//Join the threads
 for(auto &t : th1){
     assert(t.joinable())//you cannot join otherwise
     t.join();
 }
 for(auto &t : th2){
     assert(t.joinable())//you cannot join otherwise
     t.join();
 }
```

- thread.join(): the program blocks at this line until thread finishes. If thread does not finish, your proram is blocked so be careful. Note that if you don't join all thread before the end of the program, you get undefined behaviour
- thread.detach(): don't use it if you want to join, because you won't be able to do it

Comment: If a destructor is called for a `std::thread` object that is joinable (ie. `join()` or `detach()` haven't been called), the program is terminated. That may be unwanted, but it is not undefined behavior

Comment: @LWimsey Will a `std::thread`'s destructor ever be called inside `std::vector` (apart from the destruction of the `std::vector` itself)? Bear in mind that a `std::thread` cannot be copied, only moved.

Comment: @水飲み鳥 Not as long as the vector object exists.

Comment: @LWimsey Sorry, I get it now, you were actually referring to the quote: "Note that if you don't join all thread before the end of the program, you get **undefined behaviour**".

Comment: Hi, now
I have two loops now.
First for pushing treads to vector
Second to join every thread.
Different in time for 21 text file(1,5Mb x 21) is ~x8.
I don't understand, why It needs a lot of time(

Asq: when execute  - std::thread(countFile, i) <- in this moment tread stared ?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: threads are started during your push_back. Provide the time of each single thread in your question and the time it took for the program to run entirely please. This needs to be in your question